How to remove @base style from Tailwind for a single component in ReactJS?
I'm trying to render the elements created by a post using draft-js. It's raw html. So far, I could only do this using iframe; however, it doesn't look good, and using dangerouslySetInnerHTML does not get it right since it has the styles from @base tailwind. So h1, h2, and many other tags doesn't have it's default style.
Is there a way of removing the tailwind @base style from a single component, tag, etc?
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";
import { PageContainer } from "../../components/ui/page-container";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { RootState } from "../../redux/store";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import api from "../../api/requests";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { setPost } from "../../redux/slices/post-slice";

export default function PostPage() {
  const post = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.post.data);
  const params = useParams();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!Object.keys(post).length && params.postNameId && params.blogNameId) {
      handleGetPostDataFromBlog({ postNameId: params.postNameId, blogNameId: params.blogNameId });
    }
  }, [post]);

  async function handleGetPostDataFromBlog({
    postNameId,
    blogNameId,
  }: {
    postNameId: string;
    blogNameId: string;
  }) {
    const response = await api.getPostFromBlog({ postNameId, blogNameId });

    if (response.error) {
      return toast.error(response.message);
    }

    dispatch(setPost(response.data));
  }

  return (
    <PageContainer>
      <Helmet>
        <title>{post.title || ""}</title>
        <meta name="description" content="page to create post or read it only" />
      </Helmet>

      <h2 className="text-3xl text-center font-bold my-10">{post.title}</h2>

      <h3 className="text-lg text-center italic">{post.summary}</h3>

      <div className="w-full h-full border-y-2 my-5">
        {/* <iframe className="w-full" srcDoc={post.content} /> */}
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.content }} />
      </div>

      <div className="my-5">
        <h4 className="text-center text-lg font-bold">By {post.author}</h4>
      </div>

      {/* <h2 className="text-2xl font-bold">Comments</h2> */}
    </PageContainer>
  );
}


There are three methods. The prose class from the official Typography plugin might be good enough to solve your problem, and using all:revert or Shadow DOM can fully remove the preflight styles.

Typography plugin
You could install the Tailwind official Typography plugin and add prose to the class list of the div containing the Raw HTML. It changes most tailwind preflight styles like margins and dots to be similar to original, but still not vanilla as reasoned in their release blog post.
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.content }} className="prose"/>


Reset All Styles
If that's not good enough, or if you don't want to add any plugin, in your case, you could set all:initial (or all:revert to keep UA and inherited styles) on the div. Set this in the base layer in global.css so that it can be overwritten if you still want to apply tailwind classes or other custom classes defined in global.css to your Raw HTML.
@layer base {
  .reset-all * {
    all: revert;
  }
}

<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.content }} className="reset-all"/>

The drawback for this method is that you need to add .reset-all to type(tag)-only selectors such as .reset-all span{...} to have effect on elements inside the raw HTML.
This is because your selectors should contain at least 1 class-level selectors to not be reset by .reset-all. Though something like :where(.reset-all *) can lower the class specificity of reset-all to 0, some of the Tailwind preflight styles use attribute selector, which weight (0,1,n). Therefore, the reset selector needs to at least outweigh these unless you don't care about those preflight styles being applied.

Shadow DOM
One more solution, and probably the first to think of when trying to isolate child html from the outside is to use Shadow DOM. A good news is React 19 will finally fully support web components, while before that you'll need additional code to make them work with React as shown below. As the nature of Shadow DOM, anything within it won't be styled from outside of it without exposing parts or using inherited styles like color.
useEffect(() => {
    const shadowHost = document.getElementById('container');
    shadowHost.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
    // ... your code ...

    document.getElementById('container').shadowRoot.innerHTML = post.content;
}, [post])

return (
  /*Replace the div with dangerouslySetInnerHTML with the following*/
  <div id="shadow-container" />
)

